# jQuery Scroll Path plugin . "moveTo" Smooth Movement

Tags: jquery, scroll

I using jquery scrollpath plugin. Their having a moveTo function, makes sudden movement. How to make moveTo having a smooth movement (little delay or any easing) for "moveTo" f

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, ScrollPath has a animate property defined; https://github.com/JoelBesada/scrollpath ;

```
$.fn.scrollPath( "scrollTo", name [, duration, easing, complete] );
```

You can use the normal easing methods also used in the jQuery animate method; http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: It is not use for mouse scrolling. only for click event ..!

Comment: in that case I suggest you change the question: what is it exactly what you want?

Comment: i am using moveTo function while scrolling.It is working fine.but it jumps suddendly to X, Y position. not having any smooth.

Comment: From GitHub: moveTo( x, y [,options] )

Moves the center of the screen to a specified coordinate. This is done in a single step (i.e. the screen 'jumps' to the given point).